# Register Assembly em asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como usar o Register Assembly em asp.net mvc ?
Preciso criar um formulário que esta usando um reportviewer no mvc, sendo que o mesmo já existe em webforms. Irei passá-lo para outro projeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um pacote pra isso, o [ReportViewer por MVC](https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/).

[Você pode instalar ele facilmente na sua solução ASP.NET MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerForMvc/) usando o seguinte comando no Package Manager Console (*View* > *Other Windows* > *Package Manager Console*) do Visual Studio:

```
PM> Install-Package ReportViewerForMvc
```

Comment: Valeu @Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: como chamo o ReportViewer em uma página cshtml ?

Comment: O certo é chamar pelo *Controller*. [Veja este exemplo](https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started).